# error MT0026: Could not parse the command line argument '-sdk': Version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xcode14

Please help, I always have the error above when ever I try to run my new xamarin project using an ios simulator. I currently installed xcode 14 beta running on MacOs Ventura. I've been trying for days and non of the solutions I found online helped. The ios simulator list is also empty on Visual studio showing only Generic simulator and Genric Device. Please I need help

Comment: Please follow this step: Go to Visual Studio -> Preference -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Select Apple -> Browse to your Xcode installation path -> Press OK -> Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Did that a lot of time, even have to restart my system multiple times. Still no solution